# Re:processing project for UNI

Tags: processing

i m pretty sure i changed it to follow the rules so i m asking again.
The problem is that i want to shoot a bullet thats initial direction will follow the where the mouse INITIALLY was compared to location of character on mouseclick. but my code now on mouseclick will draw another bullet, but all bullets drawn will travel in a direction following an angle respective to current character location on mouseclick(which is NOT what i want)

this is an example of what it looks like

```
int bulletTotal = 5;
float[] bulletX = new float [bulletTotal];
float[] bulletY = new float [bulletTotal];
int shots;
float bulletSpeed;
float [] angle = new float [bulletTotal];
int charaStartX, charaStartY;
int charaWid, charaHght;
int sx, sy;
boolean isUp, isDown, isLeft, isRight;

void setup()
{
  size(1500,900);
  charaStartX = width/2;
  charaStartY = height/2;
  charaWid = charaHght = 75;
  sx = sy = 4;
  for(int j =0; j < bulletTotal; j++)
  {
    bulletX[j] = charaStartX;
    bulletY[j] = charaStartY;
  }
  bulletSpeed = 5;
  isUp = false;
  isDown = false;
  isLeft = false;
  isRight = false;
}

void draw()
{
  ellipse(charaStartX, charaStartY, charaWid, charaHght);
  for(int j = 0; j < bulletTotal; j++)
  {
    rect(bulletX[j], bulletY[j], 25, 25);
    movement();
    bulletX[j] += bulletSpeed * cos(angle[j]);
    bulletY[j] += bulletSpeed * sin(angle[j]);
  }
}

void movement()
{
  if(isUp == true)
  {
    charaStartY = charaStartY - sy;
  }else if(isDown == true)
  {
    charaStartY = charaStartY + sy;
  }
  if(isLeft == true)
  {
    charaStartX = charaStartX - sx;
  }else if (isRight == true)
  {
    charaStartX = charaStartX + sx;
  }
}

void mousePressed()
{
  if (shots<bulletTotal)
  {
    bulletX[shots] = charaStartX;
    bulletY[shots] = charaStartY;
    shots = shots+1;
  }
  for(int j=0; j<bulletTotal; j++)
  {
    angle[j] = atan2(mouseY - charaStartY, mouseX - charaStartX);
  }
}
void keyPressed()
{
  if(key == 'w'||key == 'W')
  {
    isUp = true;
  }
  if(key == 's'||key == 'S')
  {
    isDown = true;
  }
  if(key == 'a'||key == 'A')
  {
    isLeft = true;
  }
  if(key =='d'||key == 'D')
  {
    isRight = true;
  }

}

void keyReleased()
{
   if(key == 'w'||key == 'W')
  {
    isUp = false;
  }
  if(key == 's'||key == 'S')
  {
    isDown = false;
  }
  if(key == 'a'||key == 'A')
  {
    isLeft = false;
  }
  if(key =='d'||key == 'D')
  {
    isRight = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Also, you may want to post complete code which can be tried (or, at least an example code showing the problem which can be tried).

Comment: ok. i ll add the draw another bullet thing. as for programming language i m not too sure as this is a entry level course for year 1 students where we use an app called processing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is

```
for(int j=0; j<bulletTotal; j++)
{
  angle[j] = atan2(mouseY - charaStartY, mouseX - charaStartX);
}
```

When you press the mouse, it sets the angle for all bullets. You only want to set it for the bullet you just created. You need to delete the part above and use:

```
if (shots<bulletTotal)
{
  bulletX[shots] = charaStartX;
  bulletY[shots] = charaStartY;
  angle[shots] = atan2(mouseY - charaStartY, mouseX - charaStartX);
  shots = shots+1;
}
```